# problems in the helloworld app in Eclipse

Tags: android

I am new in developing apps for Android with Java Eclipse.
I get a simple problem: after following the procedure explained here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_hello_world_example.htm
I tried to push the "Finish" button to create my first app, but it doesn't work: the wizard remains open and nothing happens.

Also, I have several problems in the Demo apps, errors like:
'<>' source operator is not allowed for source level
and many more.

I guess I created problems with the configurations.

Thanks if you can help me to create my first app for Android and to load
the demos.

Comment: use android studio instead, eclipse is buggy ,,,https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar Eclipse isn't more `buggy` than Android Studio.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein for me android studio is much better, at least till now

Comment: You said the magic words: `for you`... ;) This, however, doesn't imply that Eclipse is buggier.

Comment: please could you help me reformulating my question? I would like to contribute in a positive way to the website and for the moment I am blocked from ask questions. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is really had to tell what is the problem, but as Abdullah advised to use android studio because it is well designed to develop android applications. and most of the  company's now days use android studio as there IDE preference, but still its developer's choice. Eclipse ADT plugin is buggy

Comment: Since the time of my answer, I work constantly on android studio.
Everything's fine except that the editor is a bit not very user-friendly.
Do you know if there are some complementary editors?

Comment: I want to advice as well genymotion. There is a plugin that allows to run the emulator from android studio. The emulator is much faster!